# Is it possible to get label of any text field inside any interceptor?

Tags: struts2, iinterceptor

I have made a custom interceptor to display the error messages in my own format. It is successful to an extent.

But i would like to know can we get label of any textfield directly from invocation object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more detailed in your requirements? Particularly what do you mean by invocation object?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the `ActionInvocation`. More details are needed. I'm curious why you would use an interceptor to customize the look of error messages. That sounds like a UI concern, no?

Answer (score 1):

If your field labels are localized, then yes, you can get the label text. Otherwise, no, since they would just be a string literal in the JSP.

Assuming you have a localized property:
field.firstName = First Name

You can get that from your interceptor using:

```
LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(
    "field.firstName", 
    invocation.getInvocationContext().getLocale()
);
```

However, if you provide more details on what you are trying to do, we may be able to offer better solutions.

Comment: Actually i m working on creating a custom conversionErrorInterceptor, where i m trying to override the default message to my own custom message. I have just replaced this statement            XWorkConverter.getConversionErrorMessage(propertyName, stack); with                                                                XWorkConverter.getConversionErrorMessage((String)stack.findValue("getText('field.firstName')"), stack);                                but in this case i need to pass "field.firstName" to get "First Name". So my query was can i get "First Name" directly from invocation object.